# Configure Travis CI to build new github branches

Tags: github, travis-ci, devops

I am using my organization account on github and I integrated it on Travis CI, however there is no webhook registered on github to notify Travis CI to pull new pushed branch.

Is there a solution or a documentation that can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to assure that Travis CI properly integrated into your github. After creating account at Travis CI you'll see all your github projects. Choose project for building and proper web-hook will be automatically created in chosen github repository. Go to **`github repository -> Settings -> Webhooks`**. You'll see the webhook:

[image: webhook in repository settings]

Also be sure that webhook have subscriptions on events:

- Branch or tag creation
- Branch or tag deletion
- Pushes
- Pull requests

You don't need additional webhook for new branches. Set up TravisCI integration and than use regular [expressions](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#using-regular-expressions) to define branches for build in ***travis.yml***. This example for builds **all** branches except **gh-pages**:

```
branches:
  only:
  - /.*/
```

For excludes use [Safelisting](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#safelisting-or-blocklisting-branches):

```
# blocklist
branches:
  except:
  - legacy
  - experimental

# safelist
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - stable
```

Comment: the problem is that github did not notify travis to pull when i push on master

Comment: I think you didn't integrate well Travis CI into github repository. Answer updated.